# Error resolving template "/index.html", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to resolve a simple index.html file with spring-boot. If I put in localhost:8080/index.html it resolves, or I get White Error Page if I do not.

I have it posted on GIT; It is a very simple app:[Git Hub Link](https://github.com/drewjocham/Portfolio.git)

The issue seem to be the model:

[image]

Form Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="applicant")
public class FormModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @Email
    private String email;
    @Size(min=2, max=200)
    private String description;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Required
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    @Required
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    @Required
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Home Controller:

```
@RestController
public class Home {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST} )
    public ModelAndView index(){

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/index.html");

        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking at your source code

The answer to your title question is:

1. You use Thymeleaf and it can resolve template `index` but not `/index.html`. TemplateResolver from Thymeleaf is responsible for loading HTML markup. By default it converts template names such as `index` into resource names like `classpath:/templates/index.html` or `WEB-INF/templates/index.html`.

   Something like this should work:

   `ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");`

But it will not fix much for you, because you also have several other things to work on

2. The image shows you use `@` for object, but you should probably use `$`, take a look at [docs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standarddialect5minutes.html)
3. Thymeleaf actually uses xml format, so you cant use your html and just add some thymeleaf form in it. You need to add closing tags for every `<hr/>`, `<br/>`  and so on.
4. You use html links like `../static/js/some.js` but you should use `/js/some.js` for more info can google how spring resolves static files

Here is repo with some fixes: https://github.com/varren/Portfolio

Comment: I have always had issues on the production server when not using `../js/sometime`

Comment: @Drew1208 yeh, can use relative path, the point was that spring path resource resolver will try to find url of `/static/js/some.js` in `resources/static/static/js/some.js`  the key here is double static in folder path